# Nativescript fails : connect ECONREFUSED

Tags: nativescript

I just update my mac to Catalina 10.15 and I get this error :
Unable to apply changes on device: B1670521954. Error is: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:62678

I am currently using NativeScript 6.1.2 and there is no problem with iOS
I have seen this :
https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/4726
but not helped in my case

Comment: I am still struggling here. Any help?